# How to auto update django model field after a day?

Tags: python, django, django-models

How can i update `is_new` field tobe **False** after a day

```
class post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    body = RichTextField(blank= True, null =True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_new = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of saving that data in the model, make a property for that value, since `is_new` is a dynamic field.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    body = RichTextField(blank= True, null =True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    @property
    def is_new(self):
        return (timezone.now() - self.created_at).days < 1
```

When filtering using ORM, you should perform checking in `created_at` attribute, since `is_new` is not stored in the database.

```
from django.utils import timezone
new_posts = Post.objects.filter(created_at__date=timezone.localdate())
```

If you want to have a is_new field inside the instance while fetching the queryset, you need to use annotate:

```
from django.db.models import Q
Post.objects.annotate(is_new=Q(created_at__date=timezone.localdate()))
```